How will plates form from this ecumenopolitan planet?
In this scenario, there is an artificial planet with a perfectly solid, Mars-like crust, meaning no plate tectonics.  This is an ecumenopolis, or planetwide city, similar to Coruscant of the Old Republic.  But this global city is not made for human habitation, but rather as foundations for soil and reefs to establish.  Ultimately, this will result in some very interesting and dynamic terrain both above and below the surface.
But for the Earth algae, plants, fungi, animals and other microbes to not only thrive but also evolve, you need the newly established continents to move.  Right away, the geology of this planetwide city is as static as Mars, but if possible, and without human intervention, how can this solid crust create plates from beneath the buildings?


an artificial planet with a perfectly solid


how can this solid crust create plates

You can't have your cake and eat it.
Plates form because the solid crust lays on a fluid mantle, which can host convective motion and carry the plates along.
You can mimic the motion with some sort of large scale conveyor belt, but that will get nowhere close to bringing new crust on the table.
